# Old site with the religious affiliations of most science fiction writers

Tags: religion, authors, web

A long time ago, when the Internet was young (*), I stumbled into a site that listed the religious affiliations of most science fiction authors, both contemporary and of the past, and bookmarked it: it was a very long and rich list that included almost every big name and several writers I hadn’t even heard of.

Then my disk broke and I lost all my bookmarks, among many other things.

Now I’d wish to browse that list again but I’m unable to find it: probably it isn’t even online anymore but I’d really wish to have it bookmarked just in case.

Does such a list or site still exist?
Does anyone know of it?
Would you share the link?

(*) As for the Internet infancy, I mean about twenty years ago: late Nineties, early Two Thousands. 2002/2003 seems most likely.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/ archives websites - some long gone.  You might even be able to find your site with an extremely well designed search.

Comment: I guess you didn't lose Wikipedia, but that's where I'd go for this info now. Also, you can now sync your bookmarks in most browsers.

Comment: @Laurel: I suspect this information may not be considered notable/relevant enough to include for many authors with Wikipedia articles, at least per [Wikipedia's policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Biographies_of_living_persons#Categories,_lists,_and_navigation_templates).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're probably looking for [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190617075634/http://adherents.com:80/adh_sf.html). It's a wayback machine (`web.archive.org`) link (from 2019; thanks to @Nzall), as suggested by @lucasbachmann. (The earliest working snapshot is from August 2000.)

1. google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22science+fiction+authors%22+%22religious+affiliations%22
2. finds this page: https://authorbib.weebly.com/science-fiction-authors.html
3. which lists this page: http://www.adherents.com/adh_sf.html
4. which is now occupied by an ad for payday lenders
5. go to https://archive.org/web/
6. paste the URL (`http://www.adherents.com/adh_sf.html`) in the search bar
7. lots of snapshots are available: the most recent ones are 301 errors or otherwise not useful.

FWIW, if you're thinking about resurrecting this list

- [this site](https://opuszine.us/posts/finding-fear-of-the-lord-lois-mcmaster-bujold-stories) states that Lois McMaster Bujold "describes herself as agnostic" (she has a ? in the posted list).
- a now deleted comment points out that Stanisław Lem was Jewish, not Catholic (referencing a [recent New Yorker article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/01/17/a-holocaust-survivors-hardboiled-science-fiction)) (there is actually some detail in Lem's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem) about his religious beliefs/claims).

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Thank you! And thank you for explaining the process of using web.archive.org, so helpful in cases like this.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190617075634/http://www.adherents.com/adh_sf.html This archive is from September 2019 and it's the most recent archive that doesn't have link rot.